# How can I put all elements from web scraping into lists

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

So I'm trying to put some elements into several different lists (that I will combine in the future). I'm trying to extract data with selenium from a web page. This is what I have until now.

This is the code I've got:

```
import time
import requests

import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import json

# Grab content from URL
url = "https://www.remax.pt/comprar?searchQueryState={%22regionName%22:%22%22,%22businessType%22:1,%22listingClass%22:1,%22page%22:1,%22sort%22:{%22fieldToSort%22:%22ContractDate%22,%22order%22:1},%22mapIsOpen%22:false,%22listingTypes%22:[],%22prn%22:%22%22}"

PATH = 'C:\DRIVERS\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
option = Options()
option.headless = False
#chromedriver = 
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox() #(options=option)
#driver.get(url)
#driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # in seconds

time.sleep(1)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)

base_municipio1 = '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div['
base_municipio2 = ']/div/a/div/div/div[2]/h2/text()'

base_loc1 = '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div['
base_loc2 = ']/div/a/div/div/div[2]/h2/span'

base_tipo1 = '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div['
base_tipo2 = ']/div/a/div/div/ul/li[1]'

base_Area1 = '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div['
base_Area2 = ']/div/a/div/div/ul/li[2]/text()'

base_ass1 = '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div['
base_ass2 = ']/div/a/div/div/ul/li[4]/text()'

base_price1 = '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div['
base_price2 = ']/div/a/div/div/div[1]/div/p[1]'



    #concat fragments municipio
listOfAllWebElements = []    
for i in range(1, 20):
        listOfAllWebElements.append(element_municipio = base_municipio1 + str(i) + base_municipio2)
        
Print (listOfAllWebElements)
#wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.='Aceitar']"))).click()
#wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@class='page-link'][.//span[.='Next']]"))).click()




#reallyLongXpathLocator = (By.XPATH, '//html//body//div//div//div//div//div[2]//div//div[2]//div[3]//ul//li[7]//a')

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="container-fluid" id="root"]//div[@class="row"]//div[@col-md-12 no-padding"]//div//div[@class="listing-search-component fullscreen"]//div[@class="mobile map-closed"]//div[2]//div[@class="pagination-component"]//ul[@class="pagination"]//li[@class="arrow page-item"]//a[@class="page-link" role="button" href="#"]').click()

#driver.find_element(reallyLongXpathLocator).click()

#driver.quit()
```

But I got this error: name 'listOfAllWebElements' is not defined

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
36
37 for i in range(1, 20):
---> 38     listOfAllWebElements.add(element_municipio = base_municipio1 + str(i) + base_municipio2)
39
40     Print (listOfAllWebElements)

NameError: name 'listOfAllWebElements' is not defined

But I've defined it above

Comment: don't believe you defined, but rather just expecting to add to it in your loop. are you wanting a list or a set? listOfAllWebElements = set() or listOfAllWebElements =  [] needs to go before your loop. for list you might want to use append instead of add

Comment: A list should do it.

Comment: I placed listOfAllWebElements = [] before the loop and change add to append
and it returned this error:
'list' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: can you update your question to include the new code? https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_append.asp

Comment: Ok I've done it

Comment: what's going on here? append(element_municipio = base_municipio1 + str(i) + base_municipio2)  Should it just be append(base_municipio1 + str(i) + base_municipio2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
prices=[x.text for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//p[@class='listing-price']")]
```

Instead of full xpaths I'd suggest something like this if you want singular lists of items.

Now if you want full items from the row you'd do something like this. Appending data to a list.

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='row results-list ']/div")
data=[]
for row in rows:
    price=row.find_element_by_xpath(".//p[@class='listing-price']").text
    print(price)
    #data.append([price])
```

Comment: You say: "Instead of full xpaths I'd suggest something like this if you want singular lists of items" but the your solution is:

rows = driver.find_elements_by_XPATH
price=row.find_element_by_XPATH.

I don't understand

Comment: When I'm trying to append a table of elements Itryed this but chrome doesn't seem to accept it:

Comment: This grabs all 20 element by the divs inside the div with class name. Its more stable incase the html elements change. The top one also grabs all the divs with the class price so it's also more stable as well.